# Parse Timestamp String with Quarter to Python datetime

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I am searching for a way to parse a rather unusual timestamp string to a Python `datetime` object. The problem here is, that this string includes the corresponding quarter, which seems not to be supported by the `datetime.strptime` function. The format of the string is as follows: `YYYY/qq/mm/dd/HH/MM` e.g `1970/Q1/01/01/00/00`. I am searching for a function, which is allows me to parse string in such a format, including a validity check, if the quarter is correct for the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: Datetime String with Quarter to Python `datetime`

This implements  a OOP solution which extends Python `datetime` with a directive: `%Q`.
Possible values: `Q1|Q2|Q3|Q4`, for example:

```
data_string = '1970/Q1/01/01/00/00'
#              '%Y/%Q/%m/%d/%H/%M'
```

> **Note**: This depends on the `module _strptime class TimeRE` and may fail if the internal implementation changes!

```
from datetime import datetime

class Qdatetime(datetime):
    re_compile = None

    @classmethod        
    def _strptime(cls):
        import _strptime
        _class = _strptime.TimeRE

        if not 'strptime_compile' in _class.__dict__:
            setattr(_class, 'strptime_compile', getattr(_class, 'compile'))
            setattr(_class, 'compile', cls.compile)

    def compile(self, format):        
        import _strptime
        self = _strptime._TimeRE_cache

        # Add directive %Q
        if not 'Q' in self:
            self.update({'Q': r"(?P<Q>Q[1-4])"})

        Qdatetime.re_compile = self.strptime_compile(format)
        return Qdatetime.re_compile

    def validate(self, quarter):
        # 1970, 1, 1 is the lowest date used in timestamp
        month = [1, 4, 7, 10][quarter - 1]
        day = [31, 30, 30, 31][quarter - 1]
        q_start = datetime(self.year, month, 1).timestamp()
        q_end = datetime(self.year, month + 2, day).timestamp()
        dtt = self.timestamp()
        return dtt >= q_start and dtt<= q_end

    @property
    def quarter(self): return self._quarter
    @quarter.setter
    def quarter(self, data):
        found_dict = Qdatetime.re_compile.match(data).groupdict()
        self._quarter = int(found_dict['Q'][1])

    @property
    def datetime(self):
        return datetime(self.year, self.month, self.day,
                        hour=self.hour, minute=self.minute, second=self.second)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Q{} {}'.format(self.quarter, super().__str__())

    @classmethod        
    def strptime(cls, data_string, _format):
        cls._strptime()

        dt = super().strptime(data_string, _format)
        dt.quarter = data_string

        if not dt.validate(dt.quarter):
            raise ValueError("time data '{}' does not match quarter 'Q{}'"\
                     .format(data_string, dt.quarter))
        return dt
```

> **Usage**:

```
for data_string in ['1970/Q1/01/01/00/00', 
                    '1970/Q3/12/31/00/00',
                    '1970/Q2/05/05/00/00',
                    '1970/Q3/07/01/00/00',
                    '1970/Q4/12/31/00/00',
                   ]:
    try:
        d = Qdatetime.strptime(data_string, '%Y/%Q/%m/%d/%H/%M')
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        print(d, d.datetime)
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> Q1 1970-01-01 00:00:00 1970-01-01 00:00:00
> time data '1970/Q3/12/31/00/00' does not match quarter 'Q3'
> Q2 1970-05-05 00:00:00 1970-05-05 00:00:00
> Q3 1970-07-01 00:00:00 1970-07-01 00:00:00
> Q4 1970-12-31 00:00:00 1970-12-31 00:00:00
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.6 - verified with Python 3.8 source***

Comment: Wow thank you for your efforts, that is exactly what I am looking for.